# Mascarar CNPJ no firebird

Tags: firebird

Estou precisando mascarar meu campo CPF / CNPJ direto no firebird, tentei o comando abaixo mas apresenta erro, será que alguém pode me ajudar?

```
UPDATE EMPRESA
SET EMP_CPF_CNPJ = 
SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 1 for 2) + '.'
+ SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 3 for 3) + '.'
+ SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 6 for 3) + '/'
+ SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 9 for 4) + '-'
+ SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 13 for 2)
```

Comment: E porque você faria isto? O CNPJ é formado apenas por números, estes símbolos são usados para facilitar a leitura por humanos na apresentação, nada mais.

Comment: Precisei mudar no sistema para deixar a máscara fixa, só que os dados já cadastrados não aparecem no campos a mesmo que eles estejam mascarados

Comment: Acredito que a melhor tratativa nesse caso seja, após recuperar os dados do banco, aplicar a máscara através da sua aplicação, antes de promover a exibição dos dados.

Answer (score 2):

No Firebird o símbolo de concatenação de Strings é o || e não o +, esse foi o erro.

```
UPDATE EMPRESA SET
  EMP_CPF_CNPJ = SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 1 for 2) || '.' ||
                 SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 3 for 3) || '.' ||
                 SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 6 for 3) || '/' ||
                 SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 9 for 4) || '-' ||
                 SUBSTRING(EMP_CPF_CNPJ from 13 for 2)
```